# Is it possible to change the margin/padding between the text and the border?

Tags: flutter, textfield

My issue is very simple to explain. As the title goes, is it possible to change the margin/padding between the text and the border in a `TextField`?
More precisely, the margin between the text baseline and the underline border of the text field.

I could brute force this and just draw a line where I want it and just stop drawing the border. but it doesn't look good with the auto error validators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass `decoration` parameter to `TextField`. It accepts [`InputDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html), which has `contentPadding` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For any Custom decoration you can you use  `InputDecoration` provided by the `TextField` widget . And from there edit the default padding or do any styling